# Podspec add static libraries for different architectures

Tags: architecture, static-libraries, podspec

I am trying to add in my `Podspec` file via `s.ios.vendored_library`, 2 static libraries depending of the architecture they're built on `arm64/myLib.a` and `armv7/myLib.a`.
But the following command seems to not work as expected as the subfolders are not imported via this.

Is there a way to import all the libraries needed, and link dymically the good library for the built target ?